# Joint distributions where one is uniform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ have a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1)$.
>
> a) Find the c.d.f. and p.d.f. of $Y=\dfrac{X}{1-X}$.
>
> b) Find the c.d.f. and p.d.f. of $W=\ln Y$.

I am extremely confused on part A, and part B also.  I get to this very early step and am stuck:

$$Y= \dfrac{X}{1-X} \\ \boxed{ F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr\left(\frac{X}{1-X}\le y\right) = \Big\vert } $$

I can't figure out how to isolate for $y$ here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please typeset your questions rather than posting links to images of text.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr\left(\frac{X}{1-X}\le y\right).$$
This is $\Pr(X\le y(1-X))$, which is $\Pr(X(1+y)\le y)$. Finally, for $y$ positive, which is the only interesting part, we have
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr\left(X\le \frac{y}{1+y}\right)=\frac{y}{1+y}.$$
Elsewhere, we have $F_Y(y)=0$.

For the density function, differentiate.

The second problem is handled in an analogous way. Note that $W\le w$ if and only if $\ln Y\le w$ if and only if $Y\le e^w$.

Comment: Huh, sad that I didn't see this algebraic method. I appreciate your help, I am on the right track now.

Comment: How would you determine the bounds that Fy(y) would take? I got [0, infinity) but I am not sure if that is correct

Comment: $X$ is uniform on the open interval $(0,1)$.  When $X$ is close to $0$, $X/(1-X)$ is close to $0$. Note that it is "never" $0$. When $X$ is close to $1$, $X/(1-X)$ is large positive. So the range of values for which the cdf of $Y$ is given by the formula of the answer is $(0,\infty)$. Almost what you wrote, except we don't include $0$. The cdf is $0$ for $y\le 0$.

Comment: You wrote "the bounds that $F_Y(y)$ would take." That's not what you meant, but the values of $F_Y(y)$ range over $[0,1)$.